# Call to coordinate for creating a patch gives an error

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, coordinates

I'm trying to construct a patch in `pgfplots` by means of table data. In attempting to do so, I also use the `\coordinate` command.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{external_data.txt}
    col1 col2
    1    5
    2    6
    3    7
    4    8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [   
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            zmin=0,
            zmax=8,
            ztick={0,8},
            z label style={rotate=90},
            zlabel=$z$,
            view={200}{20}
        ]
            \addplot3[patch,mesh,patch type=triangle]   coordinates {(0,0,0) (-1/sqrt(3),-1,0) (1/sqrt(3),-1,0)}; % Reference xy plane.

            \pgfplotstablegetelem{3}{col2}\of{\currfiledir external_data.txt}
            \edef\triangleCoordAz{\pgfplotsretval}
            \coordinate (triangleCoordA) at (axis cs:0,0,\triangleCoordAz);
            \fill[red] (triangleCoordA) circle (1pt); % THIS WORKS FINE WITH THE COORDINATE!

            \addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle] coordinates {(triangleCoordA) ({-1/sqrt(3)},-1,1) ({1/sqrt(3)},-1,1)}; % GIVES AN ERROR!
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Plotting a red circle at the coordinate with the command `\fill[red] (triangleCoordA) circle (1pt);` works just fine, so apparently, there's nothing wrong the definition of the coordinate. Nonetheless, with the last `\addplot3` command, I unfortunatelty get the error

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `triangleCoordA' (in 'triangleCoordA
) ({-1/sqrt(3)}').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.37 ...dA) ({-1/sqrt(3)},-1,1) ({1/sqrt(3)},-1,1)};

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

I can't seem to find an example of a construction of a patch using predefined coordinates in PGFplots manual.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @HarishKumar But `\triangleCoordA` defines a coordinate of the form `(x,y,z)`, so how come it's not working. Are you saying that the `\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle] coordinates {...};` is not compatible with coordinates predefined by means of the `\coordinate` command?

Comment: @HarishKumar Ok I understand. Is there an alternative way to use predefined coordinates in the `addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle] coordinates {...}` command, or is it necessary to always use commands like `(\triangleCoordAx,\triangleCoordAy,\triangleCoordAz)`?

Comment: @HarishKumar Ok. Do you want to post the final answer, or should I ;)? It would btw, still be nice to make a macro out of this I think. So, given a filename of the table data file, row and columns, the `\triangleCoordx`, `\triangleCoordy` and `\triangleCoordz` are defined. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: What kind of macro you are thinking of?

Comment: @HarishKumar A macro like I described in my previous comment. So a function with as input arguments the filename and three pairs of (row,column) for the coordinates x, y and z, and as output `\triangleCoordx`, `\triangleCoordy` and `\triangleCoordz`. You call this a amcro, right? Perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology :(.

Comment: Not that straight forward, I am afraid, so better ask a specific, separate question, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle] coordinates...` , `pgfplots` expects the actual coordinate values of the form `(x,y,z)`. But the line

```
\coordinate (triangleCoordA) at (axis cs:0,0,\triangleCoordAz);
```

defines the name of a point whose coordinates are `(0,0,\triangleCoordAz)`.

So, the instruction

```
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle] coordinates {(triangleCoordA)...};
```

provides the name of the coordinate not the actual `(x,y,z)` values. Hence it won't work.

Therefore, you have to use the actual coordinates (not the name of a point) as

```
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle] coordinates {(0,0,\triangleCoordAz) ({-1/sqrt(3)},-1,1) ({1/sqrt(3)},-1,1)};
```

unless you are ready to do a big hack.